# Deleting unused files in regular cron job

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to automate the big orange 'Clean Up Files' button with a scheduled cron job on Parse ?

I know how to write a job in Cloud Code but I don't know which method call to delete unused files.

Thanks in advance